# Monocular Rendering With Distortion Correction on Google Cardboard

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard

I'm using cardboard for something that doesn't require both eye views simultaneously. Because I don't need both views simultaneously, I'd like to save resources by not drawing the second OpenGL texture.

Is there a way to have monocular rendering with distortion correction enabled? I know setting VRModeEnabled to false enables monocular rendering, but it disables distortion correction. I noticed there's a CardboardView.Renderer class for "renderers who need to handle all the stereo rendering details by themselves" but I'm not exactly sure what that means or how to use the Renderer class on its own. I tried swapping the StereoRenderer for Renderer but nothing is drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial solution is to just execute the onDrawEye method when eye.getType() is equal to 1 (left eye) or eye.getType() is equal to 2 (right eye).

If you wanted only the left eye shown:

```
@Override
public void onDrawEye(Eye eye) {
    if(eye.getType()==1) {
        //left eye code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for CardboardView.Renderer:

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/latest/reference/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/CardboardView.Renderer

You would need to implement some different functions, mainly the onDrawFrame() method, in order for this interface to draw anything.  This is why you are seeing nothing.

The CardboardView.Renderer.onDrawFrame() method lets you draw either eye, both, or neither.  However, this interface may not do what you want, since the distortion pass still assumes that whatever you have drawn for each eye goes into the left and/or right halves of the framebuffer.  This is because CardboardView is designed to correct the distortion of a *pair* of lenses.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any chance you know how to handle the onDrawFrame() method using CardboardView.Renderer? I know I need to add code into the onDrawFrame() method, but simply copying my draw code from onDrawEye() doesn't cut it. Or do you have any other suggestions on how to accomplish this? I was hoping the distortion pass would be unaffected because I still want the left eye on that half of the screen, I just don't want to render the same texture twice if I don't have to